# Model Associations, multiple models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some models named GameItem, InventoryItem, Inventory, User, Bonuse and Bonuses_Game_Items

A User has one inventory.
A user has many inventory items through inventory.
A Game Item has and belongs to many bonuses through Bonuses_Game_Items.
An Inventory has many InventoryItems.
An InventoryItem is like (inventory_id, game_item_id).

Simply, a game item is the static representation of the item in the db, while the inventory item is the combination of an item and a user's inventory. The question now is :

how can i get the bonuses out of an inventory_item ? what are the associations that i have to use ? I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei there,

I am not sure if I understand correctly but I will try to help you, as I had a similar problem (as it seems).

First do I understand you right that InventoryItems belongs to GameItems? Is that relation defined in your models?

If so I believe something like this

```
@inventoryitem.game_item.bonuses
```

Have a look here [Rails API ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) if you have defined the relations in the models then you should be able to use the line above.

That is if your models look somewhat like

```
InventoryItemModel
belongs_to => :game_items
```

I hope this helps. Could not test as I have no Rails running on this machine.

Cheers

Comment: yeap, i actually found out the solution, but you're absolutely correct. @inventoryitem.game_item.bonuses is the correct usage and after some <%= debugs %> i saw that too. Thanx anyway :)